# Failed to use ajax transfer json data failed to insert with pdo statement and return undefined data

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, pdo

I tried to simply the code as much as possible so you can recreate the scenario. 
I do not understand why the data insert will fail since both `$('#qcategory').val()` and `$('#qtype').val()`; are all simply value =1.
The ajax will be always return error with undefined data.
I do not understand where is the data went wrong after the json passed into php.

Does it mean that once the json data is passed into php, as I decoded and return it from php?
What eaxactly is the data returned with `print $users->addQ($user)`?

It has been days I stuck on this problem. I must missed something really really important. Please help me figure this out! Will really really appreciated!

**If you do not understand the question, please inform me about what you are not clear of.
Vote down does not really help what so ever if its because you are not able to resolve the problem. Thank You**

**quiz_controller.js**

```
$(function() {
$(document).on("click", "input#done-add-question", function(){ addQuestion(this); });   
});
function addQuestion(element) { 
    alert('add_question ran!');
    $('#indicator').show();
    var User = new Object();
    User.qcategory = $('#qcategory').val();
    User.qtype = $('#qtype').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ".../controller/quiz_controller.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                //"page":page, //page: value in the url php  : currentpage: value in js 
                action: 'add_question',
                user: userJson
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus) {
                alert('add_question works!');
                $('#indicator').hide();
            },//success: function(data) END
            error: function(jqXHR, XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown,data) { 
                alert('add question error!');
                alert(" textStatus " + textStatus+" errorThrown " + errorThrown +" XMLHttpRequest " + XMLHttpRequest); 
                alert("now the data is "+data)
                console.log('1'+jqXHR+" |t|t| " +textStatus+" |e|e| " + errorThrown +" |x|x| " + XMLHttpRequest); 
                console.log('data = '+data); 

            } //error END
    });//$.ajax() END
}
```

**quiz_controller.php**

```
<?php
function __autoload($className){
    $classNameUrl="../model/$className.php";
    include_once($classNameUrl);
}

$users=new Quiz("localhost","us","pw","equizz");
/*$_POST['action'] ='add_question';
$_POST['user'] ="fs";*/
if(!isset($_POST['action'])) {
    print json_encode(0);
    print " empty! not ready!";
    return;
}
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
    $userParams = stripslashes($_POST['user']);
} else {
    $userParams = $_POST['user'];
}
switch($_POST['action']) {
    case 'add_question':
        $user = new stdClass;
        $user = json_decode($userParams );
        print $users->addQ($user);      
    break;
    }

exit();?>
```

**/model/Quiz.php**

```
<?php

    class Quiz {

        private $dbh;

        public function __construct($host,$user,$pass,$db)  {       
            $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$db,$user,$pass);       
        }
        public function addQ($user){    
            $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO eq_question1(`qCatID`, `qTypID`) VALUES (?, ?)");
            $sth->execute(array($user->qcategory, $user->qtype));       

            return json_encode($this->dbh->lastInsertId());
        }
    }//class Quiz END

    ?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form> 
                                <h1>New Question Settings</h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="qcategory" class="" data-icon="u" > Category </label><br/>
                                    <select id="qcategory" name="qcategory" required="required">
                                      <option value="1">bb</option>
                                      <option value="2">cc Operators</option>

                                    </select>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="qtype" class="" data-icon="u" > Type </label><br/>
                                    <select id="qtype" name="qtype" required="required">
                                      <option value="1">ab</option>
                                      <option value="2">cd</option>
>
                                    </select>
                                </p>

                                <p class="add-question button"> 
                                    <input id="done-add-question" type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
                                                                </p>

                            </form>
```

**Erorr console.log returned by Chrome Inspector**

```
userJson = {"qcategory":"1","qtype":"1"} quiz_controller.js:214
1[object Object] |t|t|  |e|e| undefined |x|x| error quiz_controller.js:257
data = undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

in your **quiz_controller.js** try the following:

```
$(function() {
$(document).on("click", "input#done-add-question", function(){ addQuestion(this); });   
});
function addQuestion(element) {
    var User = new Object();
    User.qcategory = $('#qcategory').val();
    User.qtype = $('#qtype').val();
    var userJson = JSON.stringify(User);
 $('#indicator').show();

    $.post('controller/quiz_controller.php',
        {
            action: 'add_question',
            user: userJson      
        },
            $('#indicator').hide(),
        "json"      
    );
}
```

in **quiz_controller.php** remove:

```
if(!isset($_POST['action'])) {
    print json_encode(0);
    print " empty! not ready!";
    return;
}
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
    $userParams = stripslashes($_POST['user']);
} else {
    $userParams = $_POST['user'];
}
```

**Replace with**:

```
if(!isset($_POST['action'])) {
print json_encode(0);
return;
}

if(isset($_POST['user'])) {
$userParams = $_POST['user'];
}
```